# Meaning of "office" as in "in the office of a wall"?

Tags: shakespeare

> This precious stone set in the silver sea,
> Which serves it in the office of a wall,
> Or as a moat defensive to a house,
> Against the envy of less happier lands.
>
> — *Richard II*, William Shakespeare.

What's the meaning of "in the office of a wall" in the second line?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. You **must** show your own research. What have you looked up for *office*? For example, [senses 2 and 3 in Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/office) can be made to fit.

Comment: If it helps, remember that Shakespeare is poetry and the language is old. So you have to reach for meaning beyond "Does he mean the sea used an office positioned inside a wall?"

Comment: _Office_ is a metaphor for 'serving'.

Comment: “In the office of” does not have an obvious meaning beyond reference to being within the confines of a room that is an office. ELU search is unproductive.  Searching for the meaning of office is little help in interpreting the prepositional idiom. The context is complex. I therefore think it an interesting and reasonable question to ask. To close this newcomer’s question merely on a formality that often is ignored for other questions seems deterrent, unwelcoming, unproductive and high handed. This closure transcends the threshold of courteous welcome. Reopen.

Answer (score 3):

The key to not being confused by 'the office of a wall' is to know that the dominant present-day meaning of *office* is many steps removed from its origin in Latin *officium*, which means duty, or an action performed out of duty. Shakespeare's use of the word is much closer to its origin than ours. In that sense, something serves 'in the office of a wall', if it performs the 'duty' of a wall, or to put it less metaphorically, if it **performs the function** of a wall.

Comment: I can confirm that the editors of The Norton Shakespeare agree that the meaning of **office** here is **function**. My copy of the SOED lists this as the second meaning of the term *office*, albeit an archaic one.

Answer (score 0):

You should have also included the next verse, which contains the recipient of all these praises:

> This blessed plot, this earth, this realm, this ***England***...

Shakespeare praises England repeatedly for its geographical position ***protected*** from any danger by the sea which surrounds it ***LIKE a wall***, thus shielding it from those ***less happier lands***.

Richard Vliet Lindabury, in his book *[A Study of Patriotism in the Elizabethan Drama](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/A_Study_of_Patriotism_in_the_Elizabethan/StqN9RnnBjMC?hl=en&gbpv=1)* (1983), shows on p. 159 other such instances in Shakespeare:

> As to naval power, it is only necessary, in order to realize its
> importance in Elizabethan minds, to look at plays which ***congratulate
> England upon her isolation***. Naturally the isolation would have
> collapsed if her harbors had been at the mercy of hostile shipping.
> Since they were not, Lyly could say with some assurance that the gods
> had pitched England out of the world, “as not to bee controlde by
> any in the world.’ Shakespeare wrote a number of fine lines upon this theme,
>
> > Let us be back’d with God and with the ***seas***
> >  *Which He hath given for*
> > ***fence*** *impregnable*
> >  <sub>(*3 Henry VI, IV.1.43-4*)</sub>
>
> and again,
>
> > That pale, that white-fac’d shore,
> > Whose foot spurns back the ocean’s roaring tides
> >  And coops from other
> > lands her islanders, . . .
> >  That ***water-walled [bulwark](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bulwark)***, still secure
> > And confident from foreign purposes
> >  <sub>(*Richard II, II.1.43-9*)</sub>

Such a use of the expression ***in the office of*** with the meaning of ***serving as***, ***acting as***, ***[serving the duty of](https://www.google.com/search?q=office%20meaning&sxsrf=ALiCzsZLcPyO5skJHL15Ve7_12lA3Q6s-Q%3A1659090410265&source=hp&ei=6rXjYqW_DdKUgQai-LTQDg&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAYuPD-oJHn1nQrvPd4_i_Oo06VQFiApTs&oq=office&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIJCCMQJxBGEPkBMgoIABCxAxCDARBDMg0ILhCxAxDHARDRAxBDMgUIABCRAjIQCC4QsQMQxwEQ0QMQ1AIQQzIKCAAQsQMQgwEQQzIHCAAQyQMQQzIHCC4QsQMQQzIKCAAQsQMQgwEQQzIKCAAQsQMQgwEQQzoECCMQJzoKCC4QxwEQ0QMQQzoNCC4QxwEQ0QMQ1AIQQzoECAAQQzoECC4QQ1AAWMwGYIwUaABwAHgAgAGIAYgBgAWSAQMyLjSYAQCgAQE&sclient=gws-wiz)*** is dated. Most of the times, it is now used followed by nouns that designate positions of authority or responsibility such as *president, director, prime minister, secretary* etc.